# Strongly normalizing type theory beyond induction-recursion

Tags: reference-request, type-theory

Are there known type theories in the literature, which have strong normalization proofs and their proof-theoretical strength goes beyond strength of type theories with induction-recursion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. System F is probably the simplest example. As far as I know, you can’t prove normalisation for it in a dependent type theory with induction-recursion — you need at least impredicative prop to do so.

Comment: Are there any references/explanations for this?

Comment: Digging around, I am confused, how does this interact with the results in https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/tree/master/papers/system-f-in-agda, which seems to use induction-recursion to formalize System F's strong normalization?
On the other hand I keep finding this dead link: http://fplab.bitbucket.org/posts/2012-12-06-induction-recursion.html as a supposed reference for this.

Comment: @Nift The "system-f-in-agda" repo does not use induction-recursion, and does not formalize strong normalization either.

Comment: Is there a reference for this claim, or is it more of a hunch?

Comment: @cody It's more than a hunch, but I don't have a reference for it. Full 2nd order arithmetic is known to be stronger than MLTT with universes (see Griffor and Rathjen). and Swedes (both actual and honorary) have told me the situation doesn't change much with induction-recursion. But I don't know the proof, don't have references, and can neither find nor construct a counterexample. Possibly Cody Roux knows more!

Comment: i managed to find a working bitbucket link, but i have yet to make sense of the broken typesetting,
https://fplab.bitbucket.io/posts/2012-12-06-induction-recursion.html

Comment: archiving it seems to have (mostly) fixed type setting so for future reference: https://archive.is/6MB4t

Comment: Is this the trick? https://gist.github.com/jcmckeown/07d844a9724745cedd61

Comment: @cody not really. The gist only uses large W-types, which is well below the strength of IR. We can try to emulate IR with large induction, using family-fibration equivalences, but we get a universe level bump in doing so. The power of IR comes from squeezing into one universe, so internal universe operators can be arbitrarily iterated. I don't know of any modeling of IR in Coq although Coq should be much stronger proof-theoretically.

Comment: ok, from what i gather we have that 1. impredicative prop can simulate IR, but bumps universe levels 2. System F is stronger than MLTT without IR by Griffor and Rathjen 3. a hunch that SN for System F can be proven using impredicative Prop and can't be proven using IR by some extension of GR's results

Comment: @Nift: I don't know how to simulate IR with impredicative Prop. What I mentioned doesn't use impredicative Prop and does not get us IR, even with the universe bump. A single universe with IR is stronger than any transfinite hierarchy of vanilla predicative universes, up to an extremely large ordinal.

Comment: another thing to add is that adding Prop breaks strong normalization by https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.08174
@AndrásKovács thanks for clarification

Comment: @Nift Notice that it does so if you have proof-irrelevant propositional equality. It's not the case in Coq, for instance, but Coq has impredicative Prop.

Comment: @Nift You can definitely prove SN for system F in Coq; impredicative prop is more than enough.

Comment: I haven’t tried to encode IR in MLTT with impredicative prop, but it is encodable in any topos using Pataraia’s fixed point theorem. I expect that if you assume function extensionality then you could redo the proof in Coq and get IR there as well.